# Any free software which counts the amount of times a noise occurs in a given video

Tags: windows, gratis, audio

I want to count the amount of times someone died during the course of a video. My idea to do this was to count the amount of times the death noise (always the same sound) occurs. Now sitting down and counting for an hour or two myself would be very tedious, and seems to be pretty inefficient anyway. This led me to wonder, is there any free software out there that could do this for me?

This software would have to

- Be able to count the amount of times the death noise occurs
- Be either very quick, or 100% independent so once started I can leave it running
- Have no virus / come without additional software
- Preferably be ad-free
- Be completely downloadable/free
- Be compatible with Windows 10

Does anybody know of software that does this efficiently?

Comment: All people die the same way with the same noise?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it's Super Mario Maker so I need to count how many times the death music plays to see how many times she died

Comment: IMHO it could be possible as it's always the same noise. But I don't know a software that does this out of the box. If I had to program this, I'd try a similar approach to auto correlation.

Comment: @Thomas I wouldn't know how to begin programming something like this, however I had the same thoughts about how it should be possible. You'd think there'd be a software that could do this.

Comment: Would you mind posting 2 sounds: the sound you're trying to find and the sample which contains that sound several times (needn't be complete length)

Comment: @Thomas I mean, I don't see why that would matter. Future readers with the same problem would need it to be a generic program anyway.

Comment: Sure, they would need a generic program. Maybe I can solve your problem first by coding something specific and then generalize it.

Comment: @Thomas Oh alright. Well I can just give you a link to the video and tell you when she started playing the level. Will that suffice?

Answer (score 0):

An audio matching / audio fingerprinting software should be able to do this. An example would be [Dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu). You may need to convert the video into an audio file first, then it could run and give you the location of matches. Which one can count automatically using Excel or similar.